# Register a static class method in a global map<>

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a main project which, depending on specific applications, includes a variety of other library projects. Those library project contain one or more implementations derived from a certain common interface.

The main project instantiates implementation classes based on a config file which contains names of the implementations to create. I want to do this by creating a global `map<>` with a key and a pointer to a factory method of an implementation. I want to do this in the library project itsself so that just including this library registers the implementations that are in that library and I dont have to specifically modify the main project other then including the relevant libraries.

note: This is a simplified version of the actual situation, but I think I have mentioned all relevant parts

How can I register an implementation with this map in the library project?

I tried the approach below, but adding the factory method to the static `factoryMap` is not allowed, resulting in a compile error `expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' when calling static method`

**Main Project**

```
class Interface {
}

typedef FactoryMethod .... // pointer to static method returning an Interface*
map<std::string, FactoryMethod> factoryMap;

class Configurator {
public:
  Configurator() {};
  static registerImplementation(std::string key, FactoryMethod method) {
    factoryMap[key] = method;
  }
};

...

void main() {
  vector<Interface*> implementations;
  ...
  // read config file and create namesFromConfig list of implementations names to create 
  for (auto name : namesFromConfig) {
    Interface* impl = factoryMap[name]();
    implementations.push_back(impl);
  }
}
...
```

**Library1**

```
class Implementation1 : public Interface {
  public:
    Implementation1();
    static Interface* makeImplementation();
};

// Following lines generates a compile error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' when calling static method
Configurator::registerImplementation("Implementation1", Implementation1::makeImplementation);
```

**Library2**

````
class Implementation2 : public Interface {
  public:
    Implementation2();
    static Interface* makeImplementation();
};

// Following lines generates a compile error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' when calling static method
Configurator::registerImplementation("Implementation2", Implementation2::makeImplementation); ```
````

Comment: have you tried put that error line to your `main()`? It is seem that you call a function at invalid spot

Comment: I didnt actually try it, but that is also exactly what I'm trying to prevent to have code refering the libraries in the main project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to execute code outside of a function. This is not permitted in C++ except for static duration variable initialization. So you could easily get rid of the compilation error by making `Configurator::registerImplementation` non void and using its value to initialize a static duration variable:

```
class Configurator {
public:
  Configurator() {};
  static int registerImplementation(std::string key, FactoryMethod method) {
    factoryMap[key] = method;
    return 0;
  }
};
```

and later:

```
namespace  {
    int dummy = Configurator::registerImplementation("Implementation1", Implementation1::makeImplementation);
}
```

or the more C-ish

```
static int dummy = Configurator::registerImplementation("Implementation1", Implementation1::makeImplementation);
```

But this would be a recipe for the C++ [static initialization fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof): the call to `registerImplementation` relies on `factoryMap` being initialized. As it is defined in a different translation unit (source file) the initialization order is explicitely unspecified. You could have this:

1. zero initialization of `factoryMap` (must occur before any dynamic initialization)
2. initialization of `dummy` in library1 file calling `registerImplementation`
3. initialization of `factoryMap` to an empty map: library1 has gone away!

You should use the [*Construct On First Use*](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use-members) idiom for `factoryMap`:

```
class Configurator {
public:
  Configurator() {};
  int registerImplementation(std::string key, FactoryMethod method) {
    factoryMap[key] = method;
    return 0;
  }
  static Configurator& getConfigurator() {
      static Configurator *conf = new Configurator();
      return *conf;
  }
  
  map<std::string, FactoryMethod> factoryMap;
};
```

You can then safely use your initializations in the library sources:

```
namespace  {
    int dummy = Configurator::getConfigurator().registerImplementation("Implementation2", Implementation2::makeImplementation);
}
```

And just change your usage of `factoryMap` in `main` (or other functions) to:

```
Interface* impl = Configurator::getConfigurator().factoryMap[name]();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following mechanism in one of my projects:

```
// register.h

[[nodiscard]] int register_function(std::string const & name, std::function<void()> fun);

void invoke_function(std::string const & name);

// register.cpp

namespace {

std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> & get_registered_functions()
{
  static std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> registered_functions;
  return registered_functions;
}

} // anonymous namespace



int register_function(std::string const & name, std::function<void()> fun)
{
  get_registered_functions().emplace(name, fun);
  return 0xdeadbeef;
}



void invoke_function(std::string const & name)
{
  auto & functions = get_registered_functions();
  auto fun = functions.find(name);
  if (fun == functions.end()) throw something;
  
  fun->second();
}


// user-code

void my_super_cool_function()
{
  ...
}

namespace {
static int dummy = register_function("super_cool", &my_super_cool_function);
}
```

Static variables (i.e. all `dummy`s inside the anonymous namespaces in the user functions) are initialized before main starts. This initialization calls `register_function` with the given parameters which adds the parameters to the global variable `registered_functions`.
So at the start of the program the map contains all functions that were registered via `register_function` and can be accessed at runtime by `invoke_function`.

Comment: @MadScienctist please explain your mechanism. How `static int dummy = register_function("super_cool", &my_super_cool_function);` suppose to work? (This mechanism is new to me)